# Find the general solution of the partial differential equation of first order by the method of characteristic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the partial differential equation of first order by the method of characteristic

$-y\frac{du}{dx}+x\frac{du}{dy}+(1+z^2)\frac{du}{dz}=0$

my idea: Is we solve by the method :$\frac{dx}{p}=\frac{dy}{q}=\frac{dz}{r}$

Comment: Hi Rajendra ! : Your idea is good, but a little short !

Answer (score 1):

System of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
First characteristic equation, from $du=0\quad\to\quad u=c_1$

Second characteristic equation, from $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x} \quad\to\quad x^2+y^2=c_2$

Third characteristic equation, from $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dz}{1+z^2}\quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{\sqrt{c_2-x^2}}+\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=0 \quad\to\quad$

$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c_2-x^2} } \right)+\tan^{-1}(z)=c_3 \quad\to\quad \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y } \right)+\tan^{-1}(z)=c_3$

General solution on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1 , c_2 , c_3)=0$, any differentiable function $\Phi$ of three variables  :
$$\Phi\left(u\:,\:(x^2+y^2)\:,\:\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y } \right)+\tan^{-1}(z) \right)  \right)=0$$
Equivalent explicit form, with any differentiable function $F$ of two variables :
$$u(x,y,z)=F\left((x^2+y^2)\:,\:\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y } \right)+\tan^{-1}(z) \right)  \right)$$